# Define variable as macro parameter

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, enumeration, nsrange

Is it possible to define a macro such that I can also define a variable which is a parameter? I want to write a shorthand enumeration for ranges in objective-c such that I have something like the following:

```
#define NSRangeEnumerate(i, range)    for(i = range.location; i < NSMaxRange(range); ++i)
```

However, when calling this macro, obviously, I get an error since `i` is not defined before calling the macro.

```
NSRangeEnumerate(i, range) {}
```

Throws and error because I need to do:

```
NSUInteger i;
NSRangeEnumerate(i, range) {}
```

What I would like to be able to do, like in a typical `for` statement is the following:

```
NSRangeEnumerate(NSUInteger i, range) {}
```

How might I go about this, because if I define `i` inside the macro, I realize it is defined two more times because of how the macro is written. I'd like it to be initialized once and then referenced the next two times. I hope my goal makes sense... Any help would be truly appreciated.

**Edit**

My current solution, although not preferred is:

```
#define NSRangeEnumerate(type, i, range)    for(type i = range.location; i < NSMaxRange(range); ++i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define NSRangeEnumerate(type, i, range)    for(type i = range.location; i < NSMaxRange(range); ++i)
```

or

```
#define NSRangeEnumerate(i, range) for(NSUInteger i = range.location; i < NSMaxRange(range); ++i)
```

Comment: I tried that latter method already. That still throws an error since `i` is not defined before calling the macro. The first did come to mind, but it just seemed a little cumbersome. I actually use the previous method right now :/

Comment: @Savagewood, I are missing my answer with `for(i = range.location; i < NSMaxRange(range); ++i)` where type of `i` isn't specified in `for` statement.

Comment: When i define the macro as `#define NSRangeEnumerate(i, range) for(NSUInteger i = range.location; i < NSMaxRange(range); ++i)` but then call `NSRangeEnumerate(i, range)` I get an error because I have not defined `i` before calling the macro

Comment: @Savagewood, so which error you have? `i` isn't defined or `i` defined two times?

Comment: i is not defined. even though it is defined in the macro itself properly, the preprocessor detects an error when calling `NSRangeEnumerate(i, range)` by itself because `i` was not declared within that scope prior to the macro being processed. Basically, it's an untyped symbol until the macro processes it.

Comment: @Savagewood, could you provide your's code with compilator errors?

Comment: wait nevermind... weird it's working now.. sorry for the trouble

Comment: it still would be nice if the typing could be done at the same time as passing parameters

Comment: @Savagewood, for typing you can use first macro. Your's code will be `NSRangeEnumerate(NSUInteger, i, range){ ..... }

Comment: Yea, but that's not my favorite way of doing it. thanks for your help